# Allways append the artifact id to the group id?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, conventions

I have work with maven for some time but I am not sure if it is always recommended to write the artifact id at the end of the group id although it is repetitive as maven coordinates would include the concatenation of the group id, the artifact id, and the version.

For example, givin a java project with package `com.example.helloword` I always do:

```
<groupId>com.example.helloword</groupId>
<artifactId>hello-word</artifactID>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

It is there a case in which it is preferred not to put the artifact id in the group id, what come to my mind is if the project is a shared module. For instance, a utility module used with `helloword`:

```
<groupId>com.example.helloword</groupId>
<artifactId>utilities</artifactID>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Is it correct? or should I append also the artifact id to the group id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* append the artifactId to the groupId. GroupIds are used to gather different, related artifacts. You do not create your own groupId for each and every artifact.

It is usually a good idea to begin the package names with the groupId. But package names can (and usually are) longer.

Comment: Does your statement include top-level projects? For example, use group id `com.mycompany` and artifact id `hello-word`.

Comment: If you have such projects, you can do that. Usually, one has different groupIds inside a company for various technical and/or other areas, like  `com.mycompany.web` for web projects, or `com.mycompany.branchx` for branchx of your company.

Comment: I see no reason why you should duplicate information in the Maven coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, I think I comprehend it better now. I think that what confuses me was that big projects like maven, name their "technical" areas as the artifact id.

Comment: Great. If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept.

Comment: Yes, I was just given more time for other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you should **not** append the artifactId on the groupId.

But I think it depends a bit on the size of the project.
As the [Maven documentation on naming says](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html)

> A good way to determine the granularity of the groupId is to use the project structure. That is, if the current project is a multiple module project, it should append a new identifier to the parent's groupId. For example,
>
> `org.apache.maven`, `org.apache.maven.plugins`, `org.apache.maven.reporting`